# angularjs routing without links

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have two problems.
First my test.html doesn't "see" the products array from his controller.
I don't know why, I have connected the controller with the html in the routing.config.js.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router", "ngAnimate"]);

myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){    
  $stateProvider
      .state("foo", {
          url: "/foo",
          templateUrl:'start.html'
      })
      .state("test", {
          url: "/test",
          templateUrl: 'test.html',
          controller:'product-controller',
          parent:'foo'
      })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/foo");
})

myapp.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, $state){

  $scope.navigateTo = function(target){
     $state.go(target);
  }
});
```

the second thing I want is that the test.html will be activated **without** the click on the link.
If the mainpage is loaded, the test.html should be loaded too.
At the end I want to delete the `<ul>` but the result should be the same.
(the foo and the dropdown).

I have made a [**PLUNK**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VFND0iWX57DclK1Hu9RM?p=preview) where you can see the problem.

The only solution I had, is to integrate the test.controller.js in the routing.config.js and the test.html in the start.html.
But i hope to avoid this because it makes the code more confusing.

I also looked at the ui-router docs but it doesn't work for me.

```
    .state("foo.test", {
          url: "/test",
          templateUrl: 'test.html',
          controller:'product-controller',
          parent:'foo'
      })
```

I hope someone has an idea... thank you! =)

Comment: Read ui-router docs and look at demo regarding nested views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take @charlietfl's advice and read up on nested views. Other than that, you had a few errors in your plunkr:

1. Forgot to load `test-controller.js` in `index.html`
2. Forgot to inject the `product-selection` module to `myapp` (so it can resolve the respective controller)
3. Forgot to add the `ngModel` to the select element in `test.html` for data binding to work as expected

Here's your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5nEShhUtKHMLFTgZsB3h?p=preview) updated with the select control populated properly.